# What is the Difference between User Interface and User Experience?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I see this term been thrown around a lot. Wish someone can explain it in simple terms. What is the difference and relationship between UI and UX?

Comment: This question isn't related to programming. Better suited as a discussion at http://ux.stackexchange.com/ for example: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/what-is-user-experience-ux

Comment: a UI with lacks UX is like a 'BAD JOKE' to which you have to explain at the end.

Comment: or UI is how it looks where as UX is how it feels....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, `UI != UX` although there's an overlap.

- The UI designer is responsible for designing screens which users will
  interact with. UX designer makes sure the interaction is a
  pleasurable one

Answer (score 3):

UX designer usually work for macro-interactions ie. how will the user journey play out from start to end. They perform research on personas, perform usability testing, etc. On the other hand, UI designers have A+ sense in developing an interface in accordance with user stories i.e UX designer's storyboard.They work on how the interactions would work out for the entire User Journey. T[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7LvQ.png) Read more on this blog [Web Design Vs UI Vs UX ..Why You Don’t Get It Right?](http://www.northstarclicks.com/web-design-vs-ui-vs-ux-dont-get-right/)

Answer (score 3):

The user interface design is the layout or the structure of the elements on the screen as well as the functional behaviour of such elements when manipulated by the user. The user interface design should be user-friendly.

On the other hand, the user experience has to do with the ability of a user to effectively and successfully manipulate a software. Some software demand that users rate them according to appearance, functionality, interactivity among others.

Answer (score 2):

Put very simply, a user interface (UI) is the thing (website/touchscreen application) users interact with to complete some task. User experience (UX) is a user's rating of how well the interface suited their needs to complete that task.

Answer (score 0):

**UI** stands for **User Interface** while  **UX** stands for **User Experience**

To make it really simple:

**Layman example:**
    When you see a car, how it **looks** that is **UI**.
  However, the **feeling** that you have while driving a car that's **UX**.

**Technically speaking:**
    UI is just a part of UX, so a good UI contributes to a better UX. For example, imagine you visit a University's website to find admissions information. Imagine the website has weird graphics, ugly fonts and you can't figure out which link to click to get the information.

That is an example of bad UI which also ruins your UX (user experience) when you try to perform any operation.  On the contrary,  if the website has appealing graphics, nice big fonts and you spot your desired information easily. That could be an example of good UI leading to good UX.

UX itself is dependent on many factors including UI such as Latency rate, Overall time to perform operation etc.

Hope this helps.